# Python Exception handling when Importing

Tags: python, exception, import

First file:

```
class E1Exception (Exception):

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x


    def raiser (self,x):
        self.x=x
        if x=='So sue me':
            raise E1Exception('New Yorker')
        else:
            try:
                number = (int)(x)
                pass
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError ()
```

Second file:

```
import e1a
from e1a import *


def reporter (f,x):

    try:
        print f(x)
        return ('no problem')
    except ValueError:
        return ('Value')
    except E1Exception:
        return ('E1')
    else:
        return ('generic')
```

Question 1:

Does the function raiser have to be static in order to be used in the second file?

The problem is the E1Exception is never caught any solution?

Comment: I edited your answer to use the code formatter. You should highlight any code that you copy/paste and click the bracket button at the top enable the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Using 'else' is probably not what you want to do. Statements in the else block are executed _if no error was raised_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the error is never "raised"

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

You have to write `raise E1Exception(x)` somewhere with some x value.

Comment: Thanks Falmarri for mentioning the error. The first code works fine, but the second 

except E1Exception:
        return ('E1')

The E1Exception error is never raised, eventhough i imported the module.

Question: The function reporter takes in a function and a variable x. can I use a fuction from the E1a module. how would it look like?    reporter (E1Exception.raiser, 'So sue me') ??

Answer (score 0):

> Does the function raiser have to be static in order to be used in the
>   second file?

Python doesn't have a concept of "static". What do you mean by "static"?

Also, I don't think you realize what `(int)(x)` is doing. That looks to me like you're trying to cast x as an int. And although it works, it's only by coincidence. What you're really doing is invoking the `int` function on `x`. So that is equivalent to

```
number = int(x)
```

That's not related to your questions, but I thought I should point that out in case anyone gets confused.